# Have configure.ac But Not autoconf. Can I Generate Configure Without It?

Tags: build-process, libcurl, autoconf

I'm trying to build curl...specifically libcurl...on my Android device; I've built OpenSSL and have cloned the repo.  Unfortunately the curl sources use buildconf, which requires autoconf, and I don't have autoconf installed.

Is there an alternate way to generate the configure script and/or the Makefile from the included configure.ac and Makefile.in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source tarballs provided by the curl project include generated configure scripts, no need for autoconf then! You can get release versions or daily snapshots from [curl.haxx.se](http://curl.haxx.se/).

The configure script is generally generated with the ./buildconf script in the curl source code root directory and it requires autoconf, automake and libtool to be installed.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've got the latest snapshot and I'm running configure now